# Cluster is still voting on which Flow is the correct flow for the cluster

Tags: apache-nifi

When I started the nodes in the cluster, and then visit the UI, I see this message on the UI and also in the logs/nifi-app.log

```
Cluster is still voting on which Flow is the correct flow for the cluster
```

As far as I know all the nodes are configured correctly,

Answer (score 3):

It takes 5 minutes to vote unless you specify a value for nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates in nifi.properties.

The default values are:

```
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=5 mins
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=
```

Comment: So what exactly nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates means?And what does it mean if we assign some value to it?

Comment: Its the number of nodes in the cluster that you want to wait for to agree on the flow. So say you have a 10 node cluster, if you set it to 6, then after 6 nodes start and all agree on the flow, everything will proceed. You generally want it to be some majority number, unless you don't care for dev/testing.

Comment: ok, got it. And if that couldn't happen before max.wait.time, then system stops, I guess.

Comment: It's whichever happens first, if the number of candidate votes is reached before the time then it proceeds, or it waits until the max wait time and then proceeds based on whatever votes it has